# Creating & Sorting Arrays CoffeeDriver

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am supposed to be creating an application to keep track of items for a local coffee shop, additionally provides a way to print out a listing of the items. I'm supposed to create a class named Item,

- A String instance variable to hold the item name
- A double instance variable to hold the price
- A constructor that takes a String and double to initialize the instance variables
- A get and set method for each instance variable

Then I'm supposed to create a CoffeeDriver with these methods:

- `sortName` – this method sorts the array of items by item name and then displays the name and price of all items on the screen
- `sortPrice` – this method sorts the array of items by item price and then displays the name and price of all items on the screen
- `main` - It creates an array of Item objects using the data above to set each Item's information. After initializing the array, prompt the user for how they want to see the list – sorted by name or price. Then call the appropriate method.

This is the code I have so far for the coffee driver. This java thing is really hard for me :(

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class CoffeeDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Item[] items = new Item[] 
        {
            new Item("Donut", .75),
            new Item("Coffee", 1.00),
            new Item("Bagel", 1.25),
            new Item("Milk", 1.50),
            new Item("Water",  2.00)
        };

        Object[] possibleValues = { "Price", "Name" };
        Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "How would you like items sorted", "SORTING",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
            possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);

        if(selectedValue == "Price")
        {       
            System.out.println("sorting by price" + items);
        }
    }

    public static void sortPrice(String[] name, double[] price)
    {   
        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        arrays.sort(price);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name[0]+ " " + money.format(price[0]) + "\n" +
            name[1] + " " + money.format(price[1]) + "\n" +
            name[2] + " " + money.format(price[2]) + "\n" +
            name[3] + " " + money.format(price[3]) + "\n" +
            name[4] + " " + money.format(price[4]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in addition to the answer below do not put you sort in main create two methods 'sortByName()' and 'sortByPrice()' in you Item class. Better to use Arraylist rather than arrays.Also use Comparator http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.

Answer (score 0):

> if(selectedValue == "Price")

Don't use "==" to compare objects. Use the equals() method.